# Issue with do while loop

Tags: c, loops

I've run into an issue with a do while loop for a rock, paper, scissors game I've written. It never breaks out of the loop. I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work. Everything looks logically sound, but maybe I'm missing something. Anyone have any ideas? While I do understand that a simple fix would be to add a `break` to each `if` statement, I want to understand why the loop itself does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int rounds,
    wins,
    max;

do {
    printf("Best 2 out of 3 or Best 3 out of 5? (Enter 3 or 5)\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &rounds);
    printf("%d\n\n", rounds);
    if (rounds == 3){
        wins = 2;
        max = 3;
        puts("OK!");
    }
    else if (rounds == 5){
        wins = 3;
        max = 5;
        puts("\nOK!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Please enter a valid option.\n\n");
    }
} while (rounds != 3 || rounds != 5);

system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

Did you tried `while (rounds != 3 && rounds != 5);` ?

Of course not! Try it and it will work. Note that every number is either not equal to `3` or not equal to `5` and hence the condition will always be `true` with `||`.

Comment: You're right, it does, but shouldn't the `||` also return true if one of the conditionals is met?

Answer (score 4):

This is why tests (predicates) should be written in positive logic. Application of De Morgan's law (duality) converts

```
rounds != 3 || rounds != 5
```

into

```
!(rounds == 3 && rounds == 5)
```

which clearly simplifies to

```
true
```

But don't feel bad. In 1998 I fixed a defect in a commercial desktop business application of this exact type!

Comment: Gotcha. Just now realizing De Morgan's law hasn't been taught to me correctly. Time to hit the books.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AND` not `OR`!

Like this:

```
while (rounds != 3 && rounds != 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

`rounds != 3 || rounds != 5` is always true - whatever value `rounds` has it has to be unequal to either 3 or 5.

You want

```
rounds != 3 && rounds != 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stopping condition is always true.

```
rounds != 3 || rounds != 5  // || = OR
```

evaluates to true for all numbers.